# 404 for lucky number tutorial

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm just beginning with symfony 3. I've install it via composer and I've the home page.

When I follow the tutorial to add the page `lucky/number`,  I get a 404 : 
http://symfony2:8080/lucky/number

But,  if I add app_dev.php in this URL  :
http://symfony2:8080/app_dev.php/lucky/number

it's working. I think it's my configuration or maybe my htaccess but i do not find what's wrong

UPDATE : htaccess :

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what is inside of your htaccess?

Comment: see my update. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to clear your Symfony cache?

Comment: Yes but still not working. Maybe it's from easyphp... very strange. mod_rewrite is activate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use the following URL: `http://symfony2:8080/app.php/lucky/number`. If it works - the problem is related to your web server configuration, it simply skips the rewrite rules. Please consider using [built-in web server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html) for local development.

```
php bin/console server:start
```

Comment: When i test on http://symfony2:8080/app.php/lucky/number, i'm redirecting to http://symfony2:8080/lucky/number and still get the 404 error

Comment: Ok it's working with `php bin/console server:start`. Strange because it's not working with easyphp even it's using the same php version.

Answer (score 1):

In case Apache is serving the symfony app, https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html suggests to require the apache-pack to add the .htaccess file to the public directory. It includes the necessary rewrite rules.

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```